# heap-buffer-overflow on address

Tags: c++, vector

Given an array containing n distinct numbers taken from 0, 1, 2, ..., n, find the one that is missing from the array.

Example 1:

Input: [3,0,1]

Output: 2

My approach is read each element and then multiply that index by -1. Whichever array index remains positive is the one that's missing (I have to handle zero separately)

My code causes a heap overflow on line where I try to multiply the element by -1

```
class Solution {
public:
    int missingNumber(vector<int>& nums) {
        bool zeroFound = false;
        for(auto i = nums.begin(); i < nums.end(); i++) {
            if(*i == 0) {
                zeroFound = true;
            } else {
                int value = *i;
                printf("Inner %d %d\n", value, nums[value -1]);
                //nums[value - 1] = value * (-1);
            }   
        }
        if(!zeroFound) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            int count = 1;
            for(auto i = nums.begin(); i < nums.end(); i++, count++) {
                if(*i > 0) {
                    return count;
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
};
```

Comment: This is some stupid challenge like hacker rank.  The result is `((nums.size()+1)*nums.size())/2 - std::accumulate(nums.begin(),nums.end(),0)`

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use a debugger.

Your problem is that after the first run through the loop, the input is `[3, 0, -3]`. When you process the final element, you try and access element -4, which is never going to end well.

Even if you use the absolute value of the element, your first run will have overwritten the last element - so you can no longer tell whether the input was `[3, 0, 1]` or `[3, 0, 2]`.

Comment: @melpomene Thanks!  Fixed.

Comment: Thanks for the taking the time to guide me. I dowloaded the debugger.